# Django 5 GeneratedField with values from foreign (prefetched) relationships

Tags: django, django-generatedfield

I am messing around with Django 5's `GeneratedField` and I am curious if I can use it to total values from a foreign, prefetched, relationship.

For example:

```
class Balance(SafeDeleteModel, TimestampModel, UUID):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    current_total = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    # new, I want to calculate the total amounts of Charges and Payments which are prefetched relationships.
    generated_total = GeneratedField(
        expression=F(self.charges.values_list('total_amount', flat=True)) - F(self.payments.values_list('total_amount', flat=True)),
        output_field=models.BigIntegerField(),
        db_persist=True,
    )
```

Where my `Charges` and `Payments` models have an FK of `Balance`

I know the expressions `self.charges.values_list('total_amount', flat=True)` and `self.payments.values_list('total_amount', flat=True)` are not valid in the `F` expression, but I am trying to accomplish something like it.

Is this possible yet?

-- I am guessing not given the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.GeneratedField):

> The expressions should be deterministic and only reference fields within the model (in the same database table)

Answer (score 0):

GeneratedField in Django 5.0 is intended for use within the same database table, allowing the database to automatically calculate their values based on expressions involving other fields of the same model​​​​. Unfortunately, this means you cannot use GeneratedField to directly compute values from foreign key relationships, like summing up related Charges and Payments, because these calculations would require cross-table queries which are not supported by GeneratedField​​.

For your requirement, you would need to either manually update the generated_total field in your Balance model whenever related Charges and Payments are created or updated or use database triggers or stored procedures for automatic calculation outside of Django's ORM.

Comment: Yes, `current_total` is updated in a `post_save` trigger with those values. I was trying to figure out if there is any workaround to be able to do it specifically in the DB. This is one of the reasons I opted to upgrade to Django 5 so early.